Sceptre CodePipeline FilePaths configuration - duplicate filters created
I am attempting to define a CodePipeline V2 in Sceptre that will be triggered if specific files are modified.
By default, all files will trigger the pipeline
sceptre template parameters
Parameters:

  FileIncludes:
    Type: 'CommaDelimitedList'
    Default: '*'


sceptre template
  CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      Name: !Join ['-', ['mrt_pipeline', !Select [1, !Split ['/', !Ref RepositoryName]], 'OnDemand']]
      PipelineType: 'V2'
      ExecutionMode: QUEUED
      RoleArn: {{sceptre_user_data.CodePipelineRoleArn}}
      Variables:
      - Name: foo
      ArtifactStore:
        # CloudFormation only supports S3 at the moment!
        Type: 'S3'
        Location: {{sceptre_user_data.S3ArtifactBucketId}}
      Stages:
        - Name: 'Source'
          Actions:
            - Name: 'Source'
              RunOrder: 1
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: 'Source'
                Owner: 'AWS'
                Provider: 'CodeStarSourceConnection'
                Version: '1'
              # See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html
              # for info on tying CodeBuild in
              Configuration:
                ConnectionArn: {{sceptre_user_data.CodeStarConnectionArn}}
                FullRepositoryId: !Ref RepositoryName
                BranchName: !Ref BranchToMonitor
                OutputArtifactFormat: 'CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF'
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: 'SourceArtifact'

        - Name: 'Build'
          Actions:
            - Name: 'Build'
              RunOrder: 2
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: 'SourceArtifact'
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: 'Build'
                Owner: 'AWS'
                Provider: 'CodeBuild'
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: {{sceptre_user_data.CodeBuildProjectName}}
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: 'BuildArtifact'
      Triggers:
        - ProviderType: CodeStarSourceConnection
          GitConfiguration:
            Push:
              - Branches:
                  Includes:
                    - !Ref BranchToMonitor
              - FilePaths:
                  Includes: !Ref FileIncludes
            SourceActionName: 'Source'

configuration parameters
parameters:
  RepositoryName: '...'
  BranchToMonitor: 'main'
  FileIncludes: 'manifest/**,design/aws-build/**'

Console screenshot
When my pipleline is created, I end up with 2 filters

My issue
The first filter is causing the build to always run.
I can delete the first filter in the console, but it gets re-created if I make a change to my sceptre config.

The solution does not seem ideal, but it does solve my issue by eliminating the unwanted trigger from my pipeline definition.
The jq command finds the push trigger that does not contain filePaths and eliminates it.
myconfig.yml
parameters:
  RepositoryName: '...'
  BranchToMonitor: 'main'
  FileIncludes: 'manifest/**,design/aws-build/**'

hooks:
  after_launch:
 - !cmd aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name my-pipeline-name > /tmp/pipeline.json
 - !cmd cat /tmp/pipeline.json | jq "del(.metadata)|del(.pipeline.triggers[].gitConfiguration.push[]|select(.filePaths|not))" > /tmp/pipeline.out.json
 - !cmd aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file:///tmp/pipeline.out.json --no-cli-pager

